# Timestamp coulmn in a table using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a timestamp column in table. If i give 1 it should take 1st timestamp column in that table if i give 2 it should take 2nd timestamp column from that table using SQL

I need to write it in sql query

Is there any logic?

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ETL_CRE_TMST
FROM EHDL_R9_26.CLAIM_HEADER
WHERE SDM_SRC_SYS_CD= 'FACETS'
```

Query submitted at: 2019-09-28 04:28:30 (Coordinator: http://sbdwn-la08:25000)

Query progress can be monitored at:

http://sbdwn-la08:25000/query_plan?query_id=414bd2b569ee57b7:8cf6005b00000000

```
+-------------------------------+
| etl_cre_tmst                  |
+-------------------------------+
| 2019-09-10 10:08:52.340000000 |
| 2019-09-25 21:01:44.484000000 |
| 2019-09-17 15:39:35.189000000 |
| 2019-09-21 18:40:37.283000000 |
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: This post doesn't make sense. Please add sample data, your attempt at the code, and the expected output.

Comment: 2019-01-01 00:00:00 , 2019-01-25 00:00:00,2019-01-31 00:00:00  i need to take 2nd date by using sql and next time i have to take 3rd date by using sql..I ak running single time....i need to take 2nd date and run after some days i need to take 3rd date

Comment: Are you saying that sometimes you want the *earliest* date, sometimes you want the *2nd earliest* date, and sometimes you want the *3rd earliest* date?

Comment: Yaa...crct i need to write sql query for that...if  there are 4 timestamps in a column...i need to take 3rd timestamp in a sql query how wil i take in sql query!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like -

```
-- For the first date
SELECT  
SUBSTRING(timestamp, 0, 19) AS "1st Date"
FROM Table

-- For the second date
SELECT  
SUBSTRING(timestamp, 20, 39) AS "2nd Date"
FROM Table
```

Comment: Query: SELECT DISTINCT ETL_CRE_TMST   FROM EHDL_R9_26.CLAIM_HEADER WHERE SDM_SRC_SYS_CD= 'FACETS'
| etl_cre_tmst                  |

+-------------------------------+

| 2019-09-10 10:08:52.340000000 |

| 2019-09-25 21:01:44.484000000 |

| 2019-09-17 15:39:35.189000000 |

| 2019-09-21 18:40:37.283000000 |

+-------------------------------+ Depends on a logic i need to take 1st date like that 2nd date  3rd date 4th date how will i take in sql?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a `case` expression?

```
select (case when @n = 1 then timestamp1
             when @n = 2 then timestamp2
        end) as nth_timestamp
from t;
```

Comment: Ya but timestamp 1 i should take from the table ,like that timestamp2 timestamp 3 , n value i will give as parameter, so if i give 5 in n value it should take 5th timestamp from that table particular column..can u guide me on this?